# Button won't click even though I can see it's taking me to the button when doing automation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2, xpath

**My code** which takes me to the button and highlights it (I'm running java scripts within Eclipse)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Save')]")).click();
```

**My HTML code**

```
<button data-v-7405e096="" type="button" class="pull-right btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

**The error**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable
>   to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   //button[contains(text(),'Save'‌​)] because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '//button[contains(text(),'Save'‌​)]' is not a valid XPath expression

Comment: <button class="pull-right btn-primary" data -v-7814d041="" type="button">Save</button>     this is the html code

Comment: no error when running

Comment: no just highlights the save button doesnt perform the click

Comment: how would i use that?

Comment: im running java scripts within eclipse

Comment: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[contains(text(),'Save'??)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(text(),'Save'??)]' is not a valid XPath expression

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[contains(text(),'Save'‌​)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(text(),'Save'‌​)]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: thats error im getting

Comment: `//button[contains(text,'Save')]` replace this

Comment: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //button[contains(text,'Save') because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[contains(text,'Save')' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: can you manually type the same rether then copy paste , there is some hidden character between `save` and ending apostrophe `'`

Comment: `]` is missing in your xpath as per  your last comment

Comment: Is it working now ?

Comment: tried still not working throwing error, if i use my code i at least get to the button.

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Save')]")).click();

Comment: Did your problem resolved?
I am facing exact same type of issue. My code which takes me to the button and highlights it. I tried with everything like id, xpath, css selector,click, submit, wait command, move to element, java script executor but did not worked out. My xpath is also correct. I checked also whether button is enabled or not. And it is enabled. Can you guys please help me in this?
Thankyou

Comment: 1. Does the button reside inside a iFrame? 2. Attach the screenshot of save button. 3. Update the HTML snippet which also contains the preceding (parent) tags.

Comment: Is this problem resolved? I am having the exact same issue

Comment: I was having the same issue, the button is retrieved correctly by Selenide but click action is not triggered so I tried this line of code and it worked with me      `Selenide.executeJavaScript("arguments[0].click();",Selenide.getElement(By.id(<button id>)));`

Answer (score 2):

**First Check the button is able to be clickable at the moment of your try. Sometimes the page load is very long it's not clickable at the moment.**

Use the below code and check

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Save')]"))).click();
```

Comment: still doesnt work, i dont get the save part to work, with the above code, when i use mine, atleast i get to the button it highlights it. my code:  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Save')]")).click();

Comment: @ShameeraRassool, just try to replace the XPath as you say "//*[contains(text(), 'Save')]" on the above code and let me know any issues.

Comment: @ShameeraRassool - Can you please accept the answer that resolved your question? Or, if you resolved it in another way, answer the question yourself and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try JavaScript executors as below,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Save')]"));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**If this doesn’t work give a wait until the element is clickable then try above code again after wait**

Comment: this has been sorted

Answer (score 1):

1. first check the xpath is correct?
2. second check if a button is enabled or disabled?
3. then click the button.

Sometimes, the button is not clickable and our script fails.

Answer (score 0):

Use assertion that the button exists, loaded and clickable. And then try to find the button by it's text.

Something like that:

```
driver.findElement(By.text("Save")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue building a test suite for our own application which uses the Angular JS Framework.

Using the following helper functions:

```
private IWebElement FindElementWithWait(By id, int timeout)
   {
       bool found = false;
       int loop = 0;
       IWebElement element = null;
       var i = timeout * 10;
       while (!found && loop < i)
       {
           try
           {
               element = Driver.FindElement(id);
               found = true;
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               found = false;
           }
           finally
           {
               loop++;

               Thread.Sleep(100);
           }
       }

       return element;
   }

private void JavascriptClick(IWebElement element)
   {
       Js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
   }
```

It's possible to overcome the issue where elements using ng-click cause an "element not interactable" exception when calling the standard IWebElement .Click() method.

e.g. `JavascriptClick(FindElementWithWait(By.XPath("//button[text()='My_ng-click_Button']"), 2));`